# Array Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''http'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in an array

Tags: php, arrays, header, file-get-contents

I just wonder, what is wrong with this code ?

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

I got an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''http'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in example.php on line  2. Any help please

Comment: _"what is wrong with this code"_ No syntax errors here, it's likely a missing quote or semicolon on a previous line.

Comment: There is no missing semicolon or quote on a previous line